# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "estar sentida" y "estar molesta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adjetivos, diferencias-entre-palabras

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "estar sentida" y "estar molesta"?

Oí a alguien mexicano decir que *estaba molesta, no sentida*.

No entiendo la diferencia.

Comment: En España solo decimos "estar molesto", nunca he oído "estar sentido". Puede que la diferencia sea solo de localización.

Comment: A como lo esuche, entiendo que uno es mas que otro, pero me gustaria saber la diferencia. Origen mexicano, por si ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 5):

En Argentina (y tal vez en otros países también) existen ciertas diferencias sutiles entre "estar sentido" y "estar molesto".

"estar sentido" (o "quedar sentido") puede usarse para referirse a una dolencia física, por lo general debida a un golpe:

- El jugador **está sentido** después del golpe que recibió.

"estar molesto" también puede referirse no tanto a un dolor sino a una molestia física (más leve y menos localizada que un dolor).

Cuando se refieren a emociones, "estar sentido" es parecido a "estar dolido", mientras que "estar molesto" es parecido a "estar enojado":

- **Estoy sentido/dolido** (triste, deprimido) porque no me tuvieron en cuenta.
- **Estoy molesto** (enojado, enfadado) porque no me tuvieron en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

En varios países americanos el adjetivo *sentido* significa **"enojado"** o **"dolorido"**. Puedes verlo en el [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=sentido). Supongo que debe haber derivado de *resentido*.

Por lo tanto, dependiendo del país, podría ser sinónimo de *molesto*, o no, eso habría que verlo caso por caso

Yo soy chileno y el significado que damos a esa palabra en **Chile** no se recoge claramente en el diccionario. Acá lo usamos para decir que estoy "ligeramente ofendido", es decir, más o menos "agraviado" o "injuriado", pero en un grado leve y en ambiente familiar.

> Estoy súper sentida contigo porque no me llamaste ayer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En México estar “sentido” hace referencia a una mezcla de sentimientos, es decir, **es estar molesto, triste y ofendido a la vez.**

Ejemplo:

- Estoy "**sentido**" por la manera que me regañó.

Answer (score 2):

En México es una expresión que se usa para expresar que no te sientes bien en relación a una persona que te hizo sentir mal. Tal vez es un modismo cultural

Answer (score 0):

Sentido : estar triste por algo que te hizo sentir mal. No estás enojado es una mezcla de sentimientos pero gana más que te  hizo sentir triste